# Basic algebra problem for weighted averages

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

This question has me completely stumped for some reason, I would appreciate a bit of help.

If you have 20 pounds of coffee for $1.80 a pound

And then add X amount of coffee for $1.44 a pound

How many pounds of coffee did you add if the final average price is $1.56 a pound.

I would really appreciate an explanation, this problem has been driving me crazy.

Comment: You should include, what you mad so far. I believe, if this problem drives you crazy, you made something. After, we will be able to customize the answer to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your equation knowing $(price\space per\space pound)\times(pounds)=(total\space price)$

$$(1.56)\times(20+x)=(20\times 1.80)+(x\times 1.44)$$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\text{Price per pound}& \text{Pounds} & \text{Total Price}\\ \hline
\text{1.80} & 20 & \text{36}\\ \hline
\text{1.44} & \text{x}& 1.44\times x\\ \hline
\text{1.56} & \text{20+x}& 36+(1.44\times x)\\ \hline
\end{array}

Edit: To add more explanation...

You are looking to create a mixture of coffee that is \$1.56 per pound.  The total value of that mixture will be $\$1.56\times(pounds\space of\space coffee)$ where 'pounds of coffee' is $20 + x$.  $x$ being the amount of \$1.44 we add.

It's total value will also be the sum of the individual values of the two component coffees mixed together:$(\$1.80\times 20) + (\$1.44\times x)$ where $x$ is the amount of \$1.44 coffee we are adding.

So, setting these to values equal to each other we get
$$\begin{align}
(1.56)\times(20+x)&=(20\times 1.80)+(x\times 1.44)\\
31.2+1.56(x)&=36+1.44(x)\\
.12(x)&=4.8\\
x&=40\\
\end{align}$$

Checking our work, a weighted average of $1.80\times 20+1.44\times 40 = 1.56\times60$

Comment: Hey Turkey,
I am still not sure on how to solve this. I tried this equation earlier but simply could not figure out how to solve it.

Comment: OK.  I'll edit a little more explanation in answer...